# Custom input:file - Prevent form submition under Firefox

Tags: jquery, forms, firefox, submit

## Goal

I'm trying to create/use a fully customizable and cross-browser CSS `input:file`. I made my input hidden and wrapped it in a button, to be able to apply CSS on this button :

```js
$('button').on('click', function(event) {
    console.log('button.click');
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(this).find(':file').click();
    return false;
});
$(':file').click(function(event) {
    console.log('file.click');
    event.stopPropagation();
});
$(':file').change(function(event) {
    console.log('file.change');
    event.preventDefault();
    // ...
});
```

```css
button {
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
}
button > input[type=file] {
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <button type="button">
        Import file
        <input type="file" name="file"/>
    </button>
</form>
```

(I added a few jQuery to link these elements together)

## Expected behavior

Under Chrome, it works like it should :

- on `button.click`, `file.click` is triggered
- we select our file
- `file.change` is triggered, and we can make custom treatments

## Issue

The problem is that Firefox reload the page after `button.click`, then we've got this sequence :

- on `button.click`, `file.click` is triggered, **and form is submitted**
- we select our file
- `file.change` is triggered, **for our old `input:file`** (which doesn't exist anymore, as the page has been reloaded)
- no change is detected for the new `file`, and we can't make our treatments

I'm not sure to be as explicit as I would like. Run the snippet under Chrome and Firefox with debug tools to see the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the `=` in `type="button"`, no?  Adding that should help.

Comment: default `type` of `<button>` is "submit" that is why it reloads the page